# How to embed flash (.swf) file in opencv project?

Tags: opencv, flash, embed

I have a .swf file, which i want to embed in my opencv and overlay over camera stream and display it to the user. Until now i have not found a solution by simple google search. I would appreciate if anyone has any idea how to approach this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OpenCV doesn't deal with .swf files**, so you need to use some other technology like [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) to retrieve the frames and decode them to BGR to be able to create a valid `IplImage` (or `cv::Mat` if you are insterested in the C++ interface).

GStreamer also provides a simple mechanism to [stream video over the network](http://blog.abourget.net/2009/6/14/gstreamer-rtp-and-live-streaming/).